# function might be possible candidate for attribute ‘noreturn’

Tags: c

```
void sbs(){
      exit(0);
    }
```

warning:

> function might be possible candidate for attribute ‘noreturn’

Getting a warning as no return.. But here the return is not called, instead exit(0) is called.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You're explicitly calling the `exit()` system call which abnormally terminates the function call.  That means control will never return to the above stack frame.

Answer (score 4):

The warning is completely legit.

Attribute `noreturn` means you should write your prototype like this:

C11:
`_Noreturn void neverreturn()`

`_Noreturn` is the attribute.

or the GCC variant:
`__attribute__((__noreturn__)) void neverreturn()`

Here its obviously `__noreturn__`.

With this the compiler can make optimizations because it knows the function never will return.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by others ,your function should give the indication to compiler that it will not return to the caller.

Please check the bellow links.

[What is the point of noreturn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-the-noreturn-attribute)

[‘noreturn’ function does return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964219/noreturn-function-does-return)